# Unable to delete Wamp folder

Tags: wampserver

I want to reinstall wamp server on my laptop. I already uninstalled the previous one. However the folder remains in C. Whenever I try to delete it, it says:

> Action cannot be completed as file opened in Aestan Tray Menu

I've no idea on what Aestan Tray about and how to close the wamp in there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

heres a good source 
Step 5 Uninstall WAMP
Go to your Control Panel (from Start) and uninstall WAMP.  Uninstall removes everything except your www and bin folders.

http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2013/07/19/12-steps-to-rebuild-your-wamp-server-without-losing-your-data/

Comment: I'm just curious how to delete the wamp folder altogether, I don't even want to back up them.

Answer (score 0):

**Aestan Tray Menu** is wampmanager i.e. the `W` icon that sits in your System tray.

Right click that icon and select `exit`. This will stop Apache and MySQL and wampmanager.

You should then be able to delete the \wamp folder completely.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: close all folders and make sure you have uninstalled wamp from control panel
step 2: click ctrl+alt+esc which opens task manager.
step 3: end task the required wamp application like database,aestan tray menu...
step 4: open your wamp folder and click shift+del

any file which are unable to delete will be running background to end task always look on task manager.